# Call template provided (static) function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers, freertos

I am trying to create a C++ wrapper for a [freertos](/questions/tagged/freertos) Task.
The challenge here is that freertos needs to take a [c](/questions/tagged/c) function pointer as described here
https://www.freertos.org/xTaskCreateStatic.html

Now I came up with this

```
template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
class CFreeRTOS_Task
{
public:
    ///Constructor
    CFreeRTOS_Task(const std::string& strTaskNameArg);
    ///Destructor
    ~CFreeRTOS_Task();

private:
    ///the Name of this task
    const std::string strTaskName;
    ///the task handle
    TaskHandle_t task;
    ///the task control block
    StaticTask_t task_tcb;
    ///is the task currently running (can be accessed from multiple threads => atomic)
    std::atomic<bool> bTaskRunning;
    ///the actual stack
    StackType_t stack[u32StackSize] = {};
    ///the task function to pass to freertos
    static void TaskFunction(void* pvParameters);
};

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++  Implementation +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
CFreeRTOS_Task<Functor_T, u32StackSize>::CFreeRTOS_Task(const std::string& strTaskNameArg) :
    strTaskName(strTaskNameArg)
{
    task = xTaskCreateStatic(
        TaskFunction, /* Function that implements the task. */
        strTaskName.c_str(), /* Text name for the task. */
        u32StackSize, /* Number of indexes in the xStack array. */
        (void*)1, /* Parameter passed into the task. */
        tskIDLE_PRIORITY,/* Priority at which the task is created. */
        stack, /* Array to use as the task's stack. */
        &task_tcb); /* Variable to hold the task's data structure. */
    bTaskRunning = true;
}
template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
CFreeRTOS_Task<Functor_T, u32StackSize>::~CFreeRTOS_Task()
{
    if (bTaskRunning)
    {
        //terminate task...
        bTaskRunning = false;
    }
}
template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
void CFreeRTOS_Task<Functor_T, u32StackSize>::TaskFunction(void* pvParameters)
{
    //do some initilisation
    for (;;)
    {
        //call the user provided task function
        Functor_T();
        osDelay(10);
    }
    //shutdown this task (common to all freertos tasks)
}
```

Now my instantiation looks like this

```
///test task function
static void TestTaskFunc();


///Test task instance
static CFreeRTOS_Task<TestTaskFunc,10> testTask("test_task");


static void TestTaskFunc()
{
    volatile uint32_t test = 0;
}
```

However I am getting 2 Compiler errors

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class Functor_T, long unsigned int u32StackSize> class NRTOS_Wrapper::CFreeRTOS_Task'
static CFreeRTOS_Task<TestTaskFunc,10> testTask("test_task");
                                      ^
note:   expected a type, got 'NRTOS_Wrapper::TestTaskFunc'
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

could you help me find out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have your class template written, `Functor_T` is a *type* not a *value*.  There are a couple of places you've gotten tripped up by that:

```
static CFreeRTOS_Task<TestTaskFunc,10> testTask("test_task");
```

Here, you're trying to pass a value where `CFreeRTOS_Task` is expecting a type.

```
template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
void CFreeRTOS_Task<Functor_T, u32StackSize>::TaskFunction(void * pvParameters)
{
    //do some initilisation
    for(;;)
    {
        //call the user provided task function
        Functor_T();   // <---- HERE
        osDelay(10);
    }

    //shutdown this task (common to all freertos tasks)
}
```

Here you are value-initializing a temporary object of type `Functor_T`, not calling an existing functor object as the comment implies.  Something like `Functor_T()()` could make sense for function-objects, but if `Functor_T` is a simple function pointer type (as in your example) that wouldn't make any sense.

---

It seems likely that what you actually need to do is store an *object* of the functor type in your class and then pass a pointer to that object to `TaskFunction`.  For example:

```
template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
class CFreeRTOS_Task
{
public:
    ///Constructor
    CFreeRTOS_Task(std::string strTaskNameArg, Functor_T functor);
private:
    //...

    using Func_T = std::decay_t<Functor_T>;
    ///the functor to call
    Func_T mFunctor;

    ///the task function to pass to freertos
    static void TaskFunction(void* pvParameters);

};

template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
CFreeRTOS_Task<Functor_T, u32StackSize>::CFreeRTOS_Task(
    std::string strTaskNameArg,
    Functor_T functor
)
    : strTaskName{std::move(strTaskNameArg)},
      mFunctor{std::move(functor)}
{
    task = xTaskCreateStatic(
        TaskFunction, /* Function that implements the task. */
        strTaskName.c_str(), /* Text name for the task. */
        u32StackSize, /* Number of indexes in the xStack array. */
        &mFunctor, /* The functor to call, passed as a parameter into the task. */
      //^^^^^^^^^^ <---- HERE, pass a pointer to the functor as the task arg
        tskIDLE_PRIORITY,/* Priority at which the task is created. */
        stack, /* Array to use as the task's stack. */
        &task_tcb /* Variable to hold the task's data structure. */
    );
    bTaskRunning = true;
}

template<typename Functor_T, uint32_t u32StackSize>
void CFreeRTOS_Task<Functor_T, u32StackSize>::TaskFunction(void * pvParameters)
{
    //do some initilisation
    for(;;)
    {
        //cast the parameter back to a pointer to the correct functor type
        Func_T* pFunctor = reinterpret_cast<Func_T*>(pvParameters);
        //call the user provided task function
        (*pFunctor)();
        osDelay(10);
    }

    //shutdown this task (common to all freertos tasks)
}
```

Then at your call site, give the *type* of the functor as your `CFreeRTOS_Task`'s template parameter and pass the *value* to its constructor:

```
///test task function
static void TestTaskFunc();


///Test task instance
static CFreeRTOS_Task<decltype(TestTaskFunc),10> testTask("test_task", TestTaskFunc);
                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    //Pass the type as a template parameter            And the value as a constructor parameter


static void TestTaskFunc()
{
    volatile uint32_t test = 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbd069a99b8b8d3e)

Comment: Thx you 2 for your quick answers :)
Unfortunately this does not quite work. I suppose ```  (*Functor_T)();``` should actually be  ```(*pFunctor)();``` right?
However static cast fails
```invalid static_cast from type 'void*' to type 'void (*)()'
   Functor_T* pFunctor = static_cast<Functor_T*>(pvParameters);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~```

could you help me out here?

Comment: Oops, fixed.  That should be a `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast` and `(*pFunctor)()` instead of `(*Functor_T)()`.

Comment: I also missed that `decltype(TestTaskFunc)` is `void()` rather than `void(*)()`.  Added `using Func_T = std::decay_t<Functor_T>` and switched to storing a `Func_T` to deal with that.  Update again, now with a working demo.

Answer (score 2):

The template type of the `CFreeRTOS_Task` is a pointer to a callable. Providing just `TestTaskFunc` will not deduce the type (i.e pointer to the function), instead, you need to `decltype` it.

```
static CFreeRTOS_Task<decltype(TestTaskFunc), 10> testTask("test_task");
//                    ^^^^^^^^
```